# node.js handlebars html file merging

Tags: html, node.js, merge, handlebars.js

I have a node.js script which i am working on.

I have multiple html files which I want to merge using handlebars into one file. This is what I want to get done.

Please I hope you do not mind the output from the editor. It kept on converting the code into html output so I had to format my output in this format.

This is my desired output the main html file.

```
 < html >
 < head > 

 < title>My node file</title>
 < link rel=stylesheet href=bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css> <!-- load bootstrap css -->
< link rel=stylesheet href=bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css> <!-- load fontawesome -->
< /head> <br>
< body> <br>
< div class=container>

< div class=col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3>

< h1><span class=fa fa-sign-in></span> Login</h1>

< form action=/login method=post>
    < div class=form-group>
        < label>Email</label>
        < input type=text class=form-control name=email>
    < / div>
    < div class=form-group>
        < label>Password</label>
        < input type=password class=form-control name=password>
    < /div>

    < button type=submit class=btn btn-warning btn-lg>Login</button>

< /form>

< p>Need an account? <a href=/signup>Signup</a></p>
< p>Or go <a href=/>home</a>.</p>


< /div> <br>


< /div>
 < /body>
< /html>
```

These are the different files

**content.html**

```
<!doctype html>
< html>
//include header.html
< body>
< div class=container>

< div class=col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3>

< h1><span class=fa fa-sign-in></span> Login</h1>

//include form.html

< hr>

//include another.html


< /div>


< /div>
< /body>
< /html>
```

**form.html**

```
 < form action=/login method=post>
    < div class=form-group>
        < label>Email</label>
        < input type=text class=form-control name=email>
    < /div>
    < div class=form-group>
        < label>Password</label>
        < input type=password class=form-control name=password>
    < /div>

    < button type=submit class=btn btn-warning btn-lg>Login</button>

 < /form>
```

**header.html**

```
  < head>
  < title>My node file</title>
  < link rel=stylesheet href=bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css> <!-- load bootstrap css -->
  < link rel=stylesheet href=bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css> <!-- load fontawesome -->
  < /head>
```

**another.html**

```
 < p>Need an account? <a href=/signup>Signup</a></p>
 < p>Or go <a href=/>home</a>.</p>
```

in php you can do something like this

include('file1.php');
some other text which can be added to the html
include('file2.php');

Comment: Show some code where you tried to compose these files, and explain what the problem was with that given code. Currently, it is not clear where exactly your problem is. There are so many possibilities. Do you have a problem with reading the files? With compiling them?  Passing them to the main template? With escaping? With the encoding? ...

Comment: I am familiar with having a single template and putting the body inside the template layout, but merging files like it is different modules I am not familiar with that. That would virtually be like calling mutliple files with handlebars {{{}}} into the template layout alone.

Comment: I am familiar with
`<!doctype html>
< html>
//include header.html
< body>
< div class=container>

< div class=col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3>

< h1><span class=fa fa-sign-in></span> Login</h1>

//include form.html

< hr>

 {{{body}}}


< /div>


< /div>
< /body>
< /html>`

but this one is merging different file for different purposes